# Does a Moroccan living in France need a visa for a stopover at London Stansted airport?

Tags: uk, france, transit-visas, stopovers, moroccan-citizens

I would like to have clarification on the following case. A person of Moroccan nationality with a residence permit (private and family life) who travels by plane to France but has a stopover in London, more precisely at the airport of stansted . The stopover lasts less than 4 hours. The question is whether this person would need a visa. If so, which one?

On this link https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/morocco/transit/somewhere_else/yes , there are indications on this case but it is not clear. I have the impression that the visa is not mandatory but I would like to have your opinion.

Comment: Stopover going where?

Comment: @MarkJohnson To go back to France

Comment: Two conditions noted in the linked site are "have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country" or "have a uniform format category D visa for entry to a country in the EEA". It also says "You won’t be able to transit without a visa if a Border Force officer decides you don’t qualify under the immigration rules. You can apply for a transit visa before you travel if you’re unsure whether you qualify for transiting without a visa."

Comment: ...and Stansted Airport [says](https://www.stanstedairport.com/help/passenger-guides/connecting-flights/) ***Connecting Flights** If you arrive at London Stansted on an international flight you will need to pass through passport control/immigration, whether your connecting flight is domestic or international. You will therefore need the correct documentation for entry into Britain.*

Comment: That should be added to the question. Transit is normally passing through a 2nd country to travel on to a 3rd country. If the goal of the 4 hours in the UK is to do something else that travelling on, then probably a standard visa will be required

Comment: The UK has signifcant covid-related obstacles (i.e., testing and quarantine) to being admitted into the UK. What is your departure airport? In what countries will you have been within 10 days of your flight to Stanstead?

Comment: Assuming you are travelling *from* Morocco, Timatic says TWOV is possible for “Nationals of Morocco making a landside transit with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country that departs before 23:59 the next day. They must: 
- have a common format residence permit issued by France, and
- clear immigration, and
- have documents required for the next destination. https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true